# moment js add function is not working

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, momentjs

Literally, moment().add() is not working in my js code.

```js
var theDate = moment(event.start.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm")); //start Date of event 
var checkquarter = theDate.add(30, 'minutes');
var plus = 30;
if (userDuration == '45') {
  plus = 45;
}
for (var i = 0; i < excludedList.length; i++) {

  var excludedTomorrow = moment(excludedList[i]["excludedDate"]).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm"); //start Date of event that should be excluded

  var endtime = moment(excludedTomorrow).add(plus, 'minutes'); //endTime of event that should be excluded
  if (excludedList[i]["id"] == 'aaa@gmail.com') {
    console.log(endtime);
    console.log(plus);
    console.log(theDate);
    console.log(checkquarter);

  }
  //var endtimeForCompare = moment(endtime);
  if (theDate >= excludedTomorrow && theDate < endtime && Id == excludedList[i]["id"]) {

    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src='https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js'></script>
```

In this code, I used moment add twice. First is checkquarter, which is added 30 minutes to theDate variable. Second is endtime, which is added plus minutes to excludedTomorrow, which I get from my DB.

Here is the console
[console response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yW1x8.png)
if you see this image, it shows the endtime, plus, theDate, checkquarter variable in order. However, as you see, nothing is added to them.

My script for momentJS is,

```
<script src='https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js'></script>
```

Comment: Don't get deceived by how its shown on the console. Did you really try to get the updated datetime from the objects? :) See [this image](https://pasteboard.co/HuRvFU2.png). If you really want to see the updated values, observe the `_d` property of the moment objects printed on the console.

Comment: careful with the moment.format() function, which will returns the string output not the moment object. So follow the golden rule USE FORMAT() AT LAST. In your example you are using the format() function in the line#1 so theDate  is no more a moment object but just a string. that is why .add() is throwing error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should clone `theDate` into `checkQuarter` as Moments are mutable.

https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/

this means that `var checkquarter = theDate.add(30, 'minutes');` is changing `theDate` and `checkQuarter` is just another reference to `theDate`.

Have a look at the console when you run the following :

```
var theDate = moment("1995-12-25 14:00");
console.log(theDate.toString());
var newDate = theDate.add(10, "minutes");
console.log(theDate.toString());
console.log(newDate.toString());
var anotherDate = moment(theDate);
anotherDate.add(10, "minutes");
console.log(anotherDate.toString());
console.log(theDate.toString());
```

Comment: Thank you!! At first, the condition in if is not working properly, so the function does not return false. at first, I think the add function is problem, but know I solve the problem that difference between var checkquarter = theDate.add(30, 'minutes'); and var checkquarter = moment(theDate).add(30, 'minutes'); first one actually change theDate value..!!!