# Moment.js adding days then get the difference in miliseconds

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have the following code, where i receive a timestamp from api then add x number of days then get the diff in miliseconds:-

```
const dateFromApi = "2020-08-28 16:36:58";
const durationInDay = 1;
var createdAt = moment.tz(dateFromApi, "Asia/Kuwait");
const added = createdAt.add(durationInDay, "days");
var diffInMilliseconds = added.diff(createdAt);
console.log(diffInMilliseconds);
```

[CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-ramanujan-rk9m5?file=/src/App.js)

The difference is always giving 0.

How can i make the above code to return the difference in miliseconds?

Comment: Why do you need Moment to get the difference in milliseconds between two days? It's a constant: 24 (hr) * 60 (min) * 60 (sec) * 1000 (ms) = 86400000.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [moment js add function is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51379397/moment-js-add-function-is-not-working)

Comment: @HereticMonkey, its just an example i gave the durationInDay = 1, the durationInDay is a dynamic value from api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in the [`.add` doc](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/)

> Mutates the original moment by adding time.

So when you do this

```
const added = createdAt.add(durationInDay, "days");
var diffInMilliseconds = added.diff(createdAt);
```

It also add to the `createdAt` itself, so no doubt compare return 0

In this case, a simple fix is to clone the createdAt into a different object, just by using .clone()

```js
const added = createdAt.clone().add(durationInDay, "days");
var diffInMilliseconds = added.diff(createdAt);
```

```js
const dateFromApi = "2020-08-28 16:36:58";
const durationInDay = 1;
var createdAt = moment.tz(dateFromApi, "Asia/Kuwait");
const added = createdAt.clone().add(durationInDay, "days");
var diffInMilliseconds = added.diff(createdAt);

console.log(diffInMilliseconds);
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js"></script>
```